# What is the best way to split letters and numbers?

Tags: php, arrays, string, function, split

I have this variable:

```
$str = "w15";
```

What is the best way to split it to `w` and `15` separately?
`explode()` is removing 1 letter, and `str_split()` doesn't have the option to split the string to an unequal string.

Comment: What would `w15g12z` give you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = "w15xx837ee";

$letters = preg_replace('/\d/', '', $str);
$numbers = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $str);

echo $letters; // outputs wxxee
echo $numbers; // outputs 15837
```

Comment: @OfirH: In future, **please make your questions as clear as possible**. State your requirements **precisely** and you'd get more accurate answers. Anyway, I'm glad to see your issue was resolved. Good luck with your project, and cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this to separate strings and numbers

```
<?php
$str = "w15";
$strarr=str_split($str);

foreach($strarr as $val)
{
    if(is_numeric($val))
    {
        $intarr[]=$val;
    }
    else
    {
        $stringarr[]=$val;
    }
}

print_r($intarr);
print_r($stringarr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
)
Array
(
    [0] => w
)
```

If you want it to be as **`15`** , you could just implode the `$intarr` !

Comment: And then you `implode($intarr, ''); implode($stringarr, '');`

Comment: up for fast and simpe solution

Comment: @sergio, Thanks for the upvote, but seems like I hit the limit and I am not getting any reps lol :)

Comment: @sergio: I don't think so. how it fast, and he is used `str_split` then `foreach` loop, then the result is `array`. in my opinion it is not fast.

Comment: @LionKing, He didn't mean that `fast` what you think as `fast`. The `fast` what he mentioned was.... I was the first to answer this question `fast`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) to achieve this:

```
$arr = preg_split('~(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])|(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\d)~', $str);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => w
    [1] => 15
)
```

For example, the string `w15g12z` would give the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => w
    [1] => 15
    [2] => g
    [3] => 12
    [4] => z
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/99837)

Answer (score 0):

Much cleaner:

```
$result = preg_split("/(?<=\d)(?=\D)|(?<=\D)(?=\d)/",$str);
```

Essentially, it's kind of like manually implementing `\b` with a custom set (rather than `\w`)

Comment: This wouldn't give the expected result - this will split the string into `w1` and `5`. But the OP wants, `w` and `15`. See [this demo](https://eval.in/99838).

Comment: Bah, my bad. Got my uppercases mixed up XD

Comment: After all, this is not [what the OP wanted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658323/what-is-the-best-way-to-split-letters-and-numbers/21658404#comment32735439_21658420). :P

Comment: Oh, ffs... I don't know why I bother sometimes XD